# changing Color of a script creates a line-break

Tags: javascript, html, css, scripting, line-breaks

I have a blog that I've been working on: calacino.tumblr.com. On the top left, I wrote a code for a bubbletab, which opens up and has some information. In that bubble tab I added scripts that update automatically. There is one 'date' script and one 'webpage-views' script. I wanted to change the color of the script.

**Here is the code for the date script:** [The webpage-views script is nearly the same]

`
    date:

```
<style type="text/css">
   div#scripteddate a 
   {
      color: #08B9FF;
      display: inline;
   }
   </style>
   <div id="scripteddate">
   <script src="http://freehostedscripts.net/date2.php"></script>
   </div>
```

`
**The section at the top sets 'date:' to the color black:**

`<span style="color: #000">date: </span>`

**Where as the section on the bottom, sets the script which gives a number to a blue color.**

`<style type="text/css">
       div#scripteddate a 
       {
          color: #08B9FF;
          display: inline;
       }
       </style>
       <div id="scripteddate">
       <script src="http://freehostedscripts.net/date2.php"></script>
       </div>`

**However, I've run into the problem that this code causes a line-break between the word 'date' and the script itself:**

http://i.imgur.com/vDirmRG.png

---

I'm trying to find a way to get rid of the line-break between 'date:' and the scripted number and 'hits:' and its scripted number.

Comment: Is it date the only one you want to change into one line or as well as the previously and hits etc.?

Comment: @Godinall, I know how to change the 'previously' because its not a script but I also want to change 'hits'.

Comment: that's simple then, just add display:inline to your #scripteddate div.

Comment: Is this your blog is made into wordpress ?

Comment: @Godinall yes haha, I put display:inline in the wrong place, thank you! :)

Comment: @DeepakGoswami no it's a tumblr blog

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS that changes color script creates a line break](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23470897/css-that-changes-color-script-creates-a-line-break)

Comment: @GolezTrol yeah I'm trying to get the guy to delete his answer but he won't

Comment: @GolezTrol hahaha omg, can you please delete it? :)

Comment: @alexthewood Okay. I did. Go ahead and delete it. Can you also delete the comments above regarding that topic? It will clean up the mess a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `display: inline` in your div not in your `a` element :

```
div#scripteddate {
   display: inline;
}
```

Because `div` element is a block-type so it's normal that it does a line-break.